# How do I pass custom field values in CiviReport urls?

Tags: civireport

For example, I have a membership report `/civicrm/report/instance/103` and I want to filter to only show rows where the value of a custom field with id of 65 is 'abc'

Answer (score 9):

`http://example.org/civicrm/report/instance/103?reset=1&force=1&custom_65_value=abc` should do it.

Note that you can also pass an operator to define the type of filtering you want to do, In this case, for example, adding `&custom_65_op=has` means that the filter would be 'custom field 65 contains the string 'abc'.

Right clicking on the relevant field in the report and then choosing inspect will open up a window where you can find the appropriate values for different operations.

Comment: Took me a while to figure this out - thought it was worth an auto q+a

Comment: Another way to get the configured values is to create a report with all filters etc, then check the table civicrm_report_instance, and then form_values from that report. All configured values are saved there and are ready to be set via URL. Seemed to be easier for me than inspecting ...

Comment: @Phil_B - interesting!